# how to share a single DB with 2 desktop app over network, app in c# and db in mssql

Tags: c#, theory

hey guys, I'm doing two desktop applications in c#. Each one is for 2 different people but the problem is both user/client want to share data between their App.  For example: The first person installs the software at his home and the second person installs the other software at his home.  Now, both users want to share a single DB.

how i should go for this? I mean, if it was a web application then i could host the database on a server.  However, since it is a desktop application, I'm confused how to do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if it would be webapp then i can host
>   db on server

You will most likely want to do exactly the same thing. You will need to host the database on a server which both applications will be able to access. Either host it yourself, or use an existing service provider who can provide hosted SQL server. Depends on how much money you have to spend on it, and how capable you are with SQL administration.

A desktop application and web application both utilise the same method of accessing a SQL database, you just hook it up through the connection string. You will have to be careful about how you manage and pass the credentials in the connection string, however, as you will need to authenticate remotely over the Internet.

Comment: thnx, so all i need is to know SQL administration and main thing is accessing it remotely

Comment: Not really, no. Make sure you know how to harden the security of SQL Server/MySQL/OtherRDBMS. It will need to be secure, so that all comes under SQL administration. But you'll also need to know how to ensure your connection string is passed securely from client to server, so that it's encrypted everywhere or not stored anywhere. If you're able to do both of those things, and do them well, you should be off to a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're going to need to set up a hosted database (web accessible), unless you want to start setting up P2P connections between the two applications which would either knowing the users home IP address or setting up a middle-man to set up the connection.

Comment: is it possible hosted database can be accessible by Desktop App,how ? and P2P is no chance not a good idea...

Comment: Yes, you can set up a SQL server and then configure the desktop application to connect to the remote SQL server. If you want to know how to set up MySQL for remote connections then you can either search the internet or ask on ServerFault.